# How To Clear Dependent Drop Down List Cell After Selecting Changed In Excel

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I don't know Excel VBA coding much. Can you please help me?
Bellow code is working perfectly with offset cell or range. But when i change **Target.Column = 5** into a single cell like **Range("B2")** and **Target.Offset(0, 1)** into **Range("B5:B10")**. It's not working.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column = 5 And Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code looks OK. Are you sure that `Target.Validation.Type = 3` for the cell being modified? In fact which is the problem? Do you receive an error? If yes (improbably, I thinbk), on what row and what error? If not, where is the problem? Doesn't it clar the value in the next column of the same row? Is it a List type validation?

Comment: But this is what your code does... It put 'null', 'nothing', "" in the cell to the right of your `Target` one... What do you want it doing?

Comment: Dear Sir, I don't want to  clear the value in the next column of the same row.
Try to understand,

Cell B2 has a dropdown list, and Range B5:B10 has dependent Items,

If cell B2 value change or Dropdown value change, Range B5:B10 should be clear.

Comment: If B2 value changes, your code does nothing, I am afraid. `Target.Column = 5` means that your CHANGED range is in column E:E, or it is a range containing more cells, but starting from column E:E.

Comment: Try, please the code I posted and see if it does what you explained (in words, in your last comment)...

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, your code should look like this. I mean, modifying B2, the range B5:B10 will be cleared:

```
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
     range(Target.Offset(3, 0),Target.Offset(8, 0)).Value = ""
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```

Or you can do it in the next way:

```
If Target.Address(False, False) = "B2" And Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
     'range(Target.Offset(3, 0),Target.Offset(8, 0)).Value = ""
     'or
     Range("B5:B10").Value = ""
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```

But, from logical point of view, this does not make to much sense, to me. You probably, need to have this behavior only if the `Target.Value` would be something that only you know...

Comment: Sir, When I change value of cell B2 it does not clear Range B5:B10.
It's clear only range B5.
Sir, One thing I want to clear to you.
My Dependent Drop-down is working perfectly.
I choose one item in range B2 and choose all dependent items in range B5:B10, one by one.
Hope you understand.

Comment: @Prabhat: Sheet Change `Event` does not care about any dependency... It does what its code tells to do. Please refresh the page (this one) and take one of the solutions I provided and tell me if they do what you explained that you need. I did not test the code in Excel. I wrote it in the answer. You maybe tested an intermediar variant...

Comment: @Prabhat: Did you refresh the page and check it? in fact, the second version works in clear as you asked in your question. If "B2" is changed, then "B5:B10" will be changed. But what about the logic question from the bottom of my answer?

Comment: @Prabhat: At what line? And, do you say that `range(Target.Offset(3, 0),Target.Offset(8, 0)).Value = ""` does not do the correct job? Are you sure that you use this code line?

Comment: @Prabhat: Did you modify the code, even if with something simple?